# in elixir how to assign value to variable from enum map result

Tags: elixir

I tried to find some answers on how to assign the result from a series of operations with the `|>` operator, such as using multiple functions with the `Enum` object, but have not found any clear example.

From my understanding, in the pipe operator chain, the last one will past the result of the operations to the next function. In this case, would this be how you would assign the result of a series of `|>` to a variable?

```
data <-
  some_list
  |> Enum.map()
  |> Enum.sort()
```

In the above, would `data` contain the value of the end result of this chain?

Answer (score 2):

In Elixir the match operator [`=`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#=/2) behaves as an assignment operator when the left hand side is a single variable. The result of evaluating the expression on the right is bound to the pattern on the left. See the [Pattern matching](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/pattern-matching.html) guide.

```elixir
result =
  ["c", "a", "b"]
  |> Enum.map(&String.upcase/1)
  |> Enum.sort()

IO.puts("Result is: #{inspect result}")
```

Output:

```elixir
Result is: ["A", "B", "C"]
:ok
```

---

You could also match individual elements:

```elixir
[_one, two, _three] =
  ["c", "a", "b"]
  |> Enum.map(&String.upcase/1)
  |> Enum.sort()

IO.puts("two is: #{two}")
```

Output:

```elixir
two is: B
:ok
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `=` operator:

```
data =
  some_list
  |> Enum.map()
  |> Enum.sort()
```